# Unable to get the inspected element in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am trying to get the dom element in a web page using chrome extension `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.` api.
Below is the manifest I have written for the extension

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Component Selector",
    "version": "1.0",
    "devtools_page": "devtools/devtools.html",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "debugger"]
}
```

The js that I have written in the devtools.js is as follow

```
function getInspectedElement() {
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    'inspect($0)',
    function (result, exceptionInfo) {
      if (!exceptionInfo) {
        console.log('Element selected for inspection:', result);
        if (result) {
          console.log(result.style);
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Error selecting element:', exceptionInfo);
      }
    }
  );
}

chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(
  getInspectedElement
);

chrome.devtools.panels.create("My Panel",
  null,
  "devtools/panel.html",
  function (panel) {
  }
);
```

Still I am getting the following error when I check the output in console
[image]

Comment: You don't have a content script per your manifest.json. Remove `useContentScriptContext: true`.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, now I am not getting the error, but when I print the result object in console, its showing an empty object.
How can I get the reference to the dom node that has been inspected?

Comment: Have added the new devtool.js file code. If you have reference to a working code or an existing project from which I can learn, that will be extremely helpful.

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not get your point. I am using the element only inside the callbak of the eval method.
Do you mean that I can't call the `getInspectedElement` method as a callback for `onSelectionChanged.addListener` method? If yes, how I am supposed to know when  there has been a change in the node being inspected.

Comment: You can only use the element inside the evaluated code. It's the first parameter of `eval`.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. It works similar to the eval function of JS. Thanks @wOxxOm!